# how to remove unused measures and columns in powerbi using Daxstudio

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure, daxstudio

I am trying to remove unnecessary columns and measures from a power bi direct query. Is there any way to identify and delete unnecessary columns and measures from the model using Dax Studio DMV ? many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible using DAX Studio.

You could try measure killer: https://en.brunner.bi/measurekiller